# Using laravel tinker and Carbon to mass update data

Tags: laravel, php-carbon, tinker

im having trouble mass updating data with tinker and Carbon as it does not iterate through the values

input

```
>>> $d = Child::get('Birthday') //1st command

[!] Aliasing 'Child' to 'App\Child' for this Tinker session.
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4195
     all: [
       App\Child {#4196
         Birthday: "2015-03-26",
       },
       App\Child {#4197
         Birthday: "2014-08-16",
       },
       App\Child {#4198
         Birthday: "2018-02-05",
       },
       App\Child {#4199
         Birthday: "1976-08-26",
       },
       App\Child {#4200
         Birthday: "1978-02-20",
       },
       App\Child {#4201
         Birthday: "2011-06-09",
       },
     ],
   }

>>> foreach($d as $ad) Child::query()->update(['Birthday' => Carbon\Carbon::parse($ad->Birthday)->format('Y:m:d')]) //2nd command
```

heres the result

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4204
     all: [
       App\Child {#4205
         Birthday: "2011:06:09",
       },
       App\Child {#4206
         Birthday: "2011:06:09",
       },
       App\Child {#4207
         Birthday: "2011:06:09",
       },
       App\Child {#4208
         Birthday: "2011:06:09",
       },
       App\Child {#4209
         Birthday: "2011:06:09",
       },
       App\Child {#4210
         Birthday: "2011:06:09",
       },
     ],
   }
```

I just want to mass update the date format but as u can see it updates everything wrong

Comment: Looks like it updated all records based on the last Birthday in the loop. You should use `$ad->update()` instead of `Child::query()->update()` - because currently you are updating all records with every iteration.

Comment: @acvi something like this? `foreach($d as $ad) $ad->update(['Birthday' => Carbon\Carbon::parse( $ad->Birthday)->format('Y:m:d')])`  unfotunately it does nothing

Comment: check if `Birthday` is in `Child`'s `$fillable` attribute, it should work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Child::query()->update(['Birthday' =>
> Carbon\Carbon::parse($ad->Birthday)->format('Y:m:d')]);

this line in your code update every row in the table, so in the last round of for each loop
this code update every row to the last birthdate.

since it is a string column you can reformat it like this way:

```
 $d = Child::get(['id','Birthday']);
foreach($d as $ad)
 Child::query()->where('id',$ad->id)->update(['Birthday' => Carbon\Carbon::parse($ad->Birthday)->format('Y:m:d')]);
```

there is a lot of format you may like in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

but I must say that this column should be a date column, not a string

Comment: yes, that much is clear from the result but I want a help or a solution to this

Comment: ok, what is you want to do, do you want to change the format of Birthday column in db?

Comment: yes, every data in the Birthday column and thanks in advance

Comment: is it string column?

Comment: `PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']' on line 1`

Comment: `Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (SQL: update `children` set `Birthday` = DATE_FORMAT("Birthday", "%Y-%m-%d", `children`.`updated_at` = 2020-10-25 16:50:35)'`

Comment: are you using mysql dataBase?

Comment: anyway, I have updated the answer to have the simplest way, but not the faster

Comment: `Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.` sorry for this